# Knocking sound after changing the brake fluid

Tags: honda, civic, noise

I have a Honda Civic Coupe 2006 with ~158,000 miles. I changed the rotors and break pads on all 4 wheels about 2 months ago. Yesterday I decided to change the break fluid. Started off with bleeding the brakes and putting the new fluid. It was fine except for the fact it looked like there was a lot of air in the hose when I was bleeding the breaks.

After that, during a test drive it was all fine. But later, when I was driving and braking at a moderate-low speed I started hearing this clicking/knocking type sound.

Now if I haven't changed the brake pads and rotors prior to that, I would've assumed it's a potential issue with them. But since I changed them 2 months ago and had no issues, it's probably something else.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you check all the wheel nuts / bolts NOW, as you likely removed the wheels to do the bleeding process.

They need to be correctly torqued to the correct value as well.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that comes to mind are the anti-rattle clips for the brake pads. I understand you've only just heard the noise recently but the pads were done 2 months ago. The fluid change could've allowed more braking pressure to be applied due to the air in the lines or more evenly and this may have resulted in you hearing the rattling. The clips or brake hardware is a really cheap kit to buy and install but just make sure you've either replaced them or re-installed the old ones at least. The clips are designed to do exactly what youd think, prevent the caliper from rattling around. Since it's only during braking events this would be my best guess.